# Binding tabselect in jquery ui tabs to initially selected tab/panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm attempting to add some event/page tracking code for piwik to tabs and contained panels of a jQuery UI widget. My code seems fine with one exception, the initially selected tab is not getting the tabselect event bound at initialization. Clicking between tabs and back to the 1st will bind the event, but I need it on page load as well so that I can track any events that occur before the user moves to another tab (if they do at all). I know I must be missing something obvious.

A minimal version of my problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/G2LS7/

Comment: Why do you want to bind a new handler function on every `tabselect` click?

Comment: @Vega - I'm guessing there is a more efficient way to go about this, but I want to pass the currently selected tab's name and the text of the link, or other interacted element in the active panel to piwik to track usage of both the tabs and the contained content. I have 2 function calls to the tracking code, 1 log for each tab click, and 1 log for any clicks to innerelements.